# How do I retrieve user input from a textbox after users hit the submit button?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Im having troubles retrieving textbox input in Xamarin using XAML and C#.

I want the user to enter their ID in a field, and after hitting the submit button, I can retrieve the value in the field.

Here's what I have so far:

XAML:

```
        <Entry x:Name="UserInput"
               Placeholder="Enter employee ID"
               PlaceholderColor="Gray"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        <Button Text="Submit"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                Clicked="GetUserInput"/>
```

Xaml.CS:

```
        void GetUserInput(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            var matchingPerson = UserInput.Text;
            Console.WriteLine(matchingPerson);

        }

 
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

However, when I call, matchingPerson = UserInput.Text, I can't access the value of UserInput. It's in a separate file and since its XAML there is no "namespace" for me to access it by.

How do I go about fetching the value of the UserInput textbox after users have entered their data in the field?

Comment: It's not in a separate file, you are calling UserInput from the code behind so it should see the Entry and the value. are you calling InitializeComponent from the code behind constructor?

Comment: @Shadi I just edited my answer to show the initalizeComponent() method, does this look right?

Comment: It depends on the name of your page, what is your page name? you would show the whole code for Xaml and code-behind please...

Comment: have you actually tried running it?  That code should be correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working fine in my side it's the issue in xamarin.forms 4.7 to get x:name in code behind

My xamarin.forms is 4.5.0.495

Xmal:

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
   <Entry x:Name="UserInput"
           Placeholder="Enter employee ID"
           PlaceholderColor="Gray"
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    <Button Text="Submit"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            Clicked="GetUserInput"/>
    
</StackLayout>
```

Code behind:

```
void GetUserInput(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var matchingPerson = UserInput.Text;
        Console.WriteLine(matchingPerson);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For whatever the reason, closing out of the solution and reopening it allowed it to run. Xamarin was somehow reporting a false error to me in the console. The code above is correct - Xamarin was being buggy. I forced quit all of my visual studio applications in activity monitor and opened them back up - that did the trick.